# Twillio SMS and .net Sending to multiple phone numbers

Tags: asp.net, .net, sms

I am using a listview to get a string of phone numbers to send the sms to. I am testing the listview with only 2 phone numbers in it, and it attempts to send the 2 numbers combined together into one 20 digit number and I get the error, "The 'To' number xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is not a valid phone number.

If I take one phone number off the listview it goes through just fine because it is only getting one 10 digit number, instead of one 20 digit number when I use 2 numbers in the listview.

```
Dim accountSid As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID")
Dim authToken As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN")

Dim list as List(Of String) = New LIst(Of String)
Dim Nums As String = ""

For Each currentItem In lbEmail1.Items
List.Add(currentItem.Text)
Next

Nums = String.Join(", ", List)
Dim MultiNums As String() = {Nums.ToString()}
 
        For i As Integer = 0 To MultiNums.Length - 1
            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken)
            Dim message = MessageResource.Create(body:="Sent thru an Array in C# with Twilio!", from:=New Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+xxxxxxxxxx"), [to]:=New Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(MultiNums(i)))
            Console.WriteLine(message.Sid)
        Next
```

If, instead of using the listview, and I specify the values as such below it works just fine and sends it to the 2 numbers just fine. So I think it is just the formatting of the numbers in how the string is joined maybe?

```
Dim MultiNums As String() = {"xxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code MultiNums is an array that has only one element with the value of all phone numbers separated by string. It should be an array of individual phone numbers instead.

```
Nums = String.Join(", ", List)
Dim MultiNums As String() = {Nums.ToString()}
```

```
Dim mylist As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
For Each currentItem In lbEmail1.Items
    mylist.Add(currentItem.Text)
Next
For i As Integer = 0 To mylist.Count - 1
   ...
Next
```

Comment: With your code, I get the error: 'Length' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)', which doesn't make sense because 'Length' is for arrays and you said your code is creating an array?

Comment: I changed .Length to .Count and it works. Update your answer to .Count and I will mark as answer. Thanks!